# Is possible to avoid updating entity when I add a item to ManyToMany relationship in Hibernate, Jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below the code Hibernate updating not changed entity, Is it possible to avoid updating.
Look at the Book, Shelf entities, and BookShelfService and Logs.

How Can I avoid updating an entity When I didn't change anything

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Book(
        @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null,
        var name: String?,
)

@Entity
data class Shelf(
        @Id var id: Long?,
        var name: String?,
        @ManyToMany
        var books: MutableSet<Book> = HashSet<Book>(),
        @Version
        @Column(name = "version", columnDefinition = "integer default 0", nullable = false)
        var version: Int = 0
)


interface BookRepo : JpaRepository<Book, Long>
interface ShelfRepo : JpaRepository<Shelf, Long>

@Service
class BookShelfService(
        private val bookRepo: BookRepo,
        private val shelfRepo: ShelfRepo
) {
    fun addNewBook(newBookName: String): Shelf {
        val shelf = shelfRepo.findById(1).orElseGet {
            Shelf(
                    id = 1,
                    name = "Shelf",
                    books = HashSet()
            )
        }

        val book = Book(name = newBookName)

        bookRepo.save(book)
        shelf.books.add(book)
        // this will also update shelf entity, But I don't wanna update it, because I didn't change anything
        shelfRepo.save(shelf)
        return shelf;
    }
}
```

Logs from Hibernate generated queries

```
Hibernate: select shelf0_.id as id1_3_0_, shelf0_.name as name2_3_0_, shelf0_.version as version3_3_0_ from shelf shelf0_ where shelf0_.id=?
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into book (name, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select books0_.shelf_id as shelf_id1_4_0_, books0_.books_id as books_id2_4_0_, book1_.id as id1_0_1_, book1_.name as name2_0_1_ from shelf_books books0_ inner join book book1_ on books0_.books_id=book1_.id where books0_.shelf_id=?
** Hibernate: update shelf set name=?, version=? where id=? and version=?
Hibernate: insert into shelf_books (shelf_id, books_id) values (?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your approach is not wrong. Because when updating book table you have 3 tables.
book, shelf, and shelf_books are three tables. The relation table has to be updated when inserting books because it has relation with shelf.

Consider that if you do not update relation table then your book and shelf do not have relation information.

Comment: Let's say we already have book(id=1) and shelf(id=2), I'm going to connect that, Should I use native SQL, insert it into shelf_books table

Comment: No there is no need to use native query. You can simply avoid using cascade.PERSIST.
If you specify cascade type you can use it by calling externally.

Comment: I think this for the version column, When I remove the version column, Hibernate not update shelf table

Comment: optimistic lock can cause that issue as well.